# In Excel VBA, how to change the color of the text of the button in a cell based upon the value of another cell in the same column?

Tags: excel-2010

I'd like a subroutine to execute upon opening the workbook (no button clicking happening) and for a specific sheet in the workbook, do the following.

Change the color of the text of the form control button (NOT ActiveX) in a cell based upon the value of another cell in the same column (on a different row).

There will be multiple buttons to do this each having a corresponding value in a different cell (on a different row) to interrogate and then change the button's text color.

To start, on line 12, column B and traversing to Column M, if the value is greater than 0, I want the text of the button in the same column to change to red. So on line 14, those buttons from column B and traversing to Column M.

Here is code I placed in the Open of the workbook. It can traverse row 12 just fine.

How do I get a reference to row 14's button so that I can change the color of the button's text?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Dim colRange As String
   colRange = "B12:M12"

   ' Set the worksheet name.
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ForIrsIncomeAndExpenses")

   With ws
       For Each cell In Range(colRange)
           ' Change row 14's button's text color to red if this cell value is greater than 0. This cell here is row 12 based upon 'Cell' from the 'For Each'.
           ' Change row 14's button's text color to black if the cell value is not greater than 0. This cell here is row 12 based upon 'Cell' from the 'For Each'.
           If cell.Value > 0 Then
              ' How do I get a reference to the button on row 14 for this column(cell)?
              ' btn.Font.Color = vbRed
              MsgBox ">0"
        Else
              ' How do I get a reference to the button on row 14 for this column(cell)?
              ' btn.Font.Color = vbBlack
              MsgBox "=0"
           End If
       Next cell
   End With
End Sub
```

Here is the sheet.

[image]